# I can not get php produced json data with d3.json

Tags: php, d3.js, data-visualization

I have developed a php app (data1.php) which produces json output from MySQL :

**PHP**

```
$username = "alitest"; 
$password = "aliden07";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="ali_app";

$server = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysqli_select_db($server,$database);

$myquery = "select Letter as  '\"Letter\"', CAST(Freq as unsigned) as '\"Freq\"' from datajson";
$query = mysqli_query($server,$myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);     

mysqli_close($server);
```

in html file I want to get the json data with d3.json command. I will produce a bar chart with the returned data.

**HTML** with js and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style>
        .bar{
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .bar:hover{
            fill: brown;
        }

        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // set the dimensions of the canvas
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        // define the axis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")


        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(10);

        // add the SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // load the data
        d3.json("http://localhost:8081/php/data1.php", function(error, data) {

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.Letter = d.Letter;
                d.Freq = +d.Freq;
            });

            // scale the range of the data
            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Freq; })]);

            // add axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 5)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Frequency");

            // Add bar chart
            svg.selectAll("bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { 
                    return x(d.Letter); 
                })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return y(d.Freq); 
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) { 
                    return height - y(d.Freq); 
                });
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

I have tried running the app with two http servers (servez and npm install http-server -g).

For serving php I have installed wamp server. 
When I change the input of the d3.json command with a local file it works but when I give a link to php file I can not see the chart.

```
// load the data
d3.json("data1_db_out1.json", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Letter = d.Letter;
        d.Freq = +d.Freq;
    });
```

I try them on my desktop.

- http-server : localhost:8080
- wamp        : localhost 8081

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, on your code we don't see `<head>` and `<body>` so you have, scripts, html tags and css inline styles in a non conventional html structure. Is javascript running like this !?

Comment: Sorry. copy problem . In the original file <head> and <body> sections are present.

Comment: So, after your last update, we see the `<meta charset="utf-8">` outside `<head>`. It needs to be into. but not so important.
Maybe you need a document.ready function to wait the page load before execute your script.

Haev you got an example of what is out from http://localhost:8081/php/data1.php??

I made a fiddle with your code, but not working if we haven't access to your json result. https://jsfiddle.net/veuaotjz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be cross-origin issue. Try to enable CORS in your json response:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Enabling CORS in my json response has solved my problem. I can see the chart now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get when I run http://localhost:8081/php/data1.php on wamp server :

[
{
Letter: "A",
Freq: 25
},
{
Letter: "B",
Freq: 12
},
{
Letter: "C",
Freq: 47
},
{
Letter: "D",
Freq: 34
},
{
Letter: "E",
Freq: 54
},
{
Letter: "F",
Freq: 21
},
{
Letter: "G",
Freq: 57
},
{
Letter: "H",
Freq: 31
},
{
Letter: "I",
Freq: 17
},
{
Letter: "J",
Freq: 5
},
{
Letter: "K",
Freq: 23
},
{
Letter: "L",
Freq: 39
},
{
Letter: "M",
Freq: 29
},
{
Letter: "N",
Freq: 33
},
{
Letter: "O",
Freq: 18
},
{
Letter: "P",
Freq: 35
},
{
Letter: "Q",
Freq: 11
},
{
Letter: "R",
Freq: 45
},
{
Letter: "S",
Freq: 43
},
{
Letter: "T",
Freq: 28
},
{
Letter: "U",
Freq: 26
},
{
Letter: "V",
Freq: 30
},
{
Letter: "X",
Freq: 5
},
{
Letter: "Y",
Freq: 4
},
{
Letter: "Z",
Freq: 2
}
]

Answer (score 0):

And I have changed the query string in data1.php. The current running version is :

```
<?php
    $username = "alitest"; 
    $password = "aliden07";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="ali_app";

    $server = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysqli_select_db($server,$database);

    //$myquery = "select Letter as  '\"Letter\"', CAST(Freq as unsigned) as '\"Freq\"' from datajson";
    $myquery = "select Letter , CAST(Freq as unsigned) as Freq  from datajson";
    $query = mysqli_query($server,$myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysqli_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    //header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);     

    mysqli_close($server);
?>
```